# How to create a border on a Widget with an ImageView?

Tags: android, xml, flutter, widget

i want to create a xml file that displays a image on the screen with transparent border. I can only use xml.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I work with Flutter

[image: Example of Homescreen Widget]

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for Create rounded image view

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
 
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
 
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter Image - tutorialkart.com'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.cyan,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 200,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  child: Image(
                    image: NetworkImage(
                        'https://www.tutorialkart.com/img/hummingbird.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 200,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  child: Image(
                    image: NetworkImage(
                        'https://www.tutorialkart.com/img/hummingbird.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```